# Parsing a FIRHTTPSCallableResult object data from Firebase Cloud Function with Swift

Tags: ios, json, swift, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I have this simple Cloud Function:

```
export const getTasks = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
    admin.firestore().collection('tasks').get()
    .then(snapshot => {
        const results = []
        snapshot.forEach(task => {
            const data = task.data()
            results.push(data)
        })
        response.send(results)
    })
    .catch(error => {
        console.log(error)
        response.status(500).send(error)
    })
});
```

The https call, from the browser, gives me a correct json:

```
[
{
title: "A title",
dueDate: "2018-07-03T18:33:27.537Z",
isComplete: true,
type: "task",
date: "2018-07-02T18:33:27.537Z"
},
{
type: "task",
date: "2018-07-02T18:36:25.506Z",
title: "Wowo",
dueDate: "2018-07-02T21:59:59.000Z",
isComplete: true
},
{
title: "Abc",
dueDate: "2018-07-04T18:31:58.050Z",
isComplete: false,
type: "task",
date: "2018-07-02T18:31:58.050Z"
}
]
```

But when I try to receive data from the iOS client through the function, I get a **FIRHTTPSCallableResult** object and a nil object:

```
functions.httpsCallable("getTasks").call() { (result, error) in
            if let error = error as NSError? {
                if error.domain == FunctionsErrorDomain {
                    //...
                }
                // ...
            }

            print( "result -> \(type(of: result))")
            print( "result?.data -> \(type(of: result?.data))")
```

Log:

```
result -> Optional<FIRHTTPSCallableResult>

result?.data -> Optional<Any>
```

I tried to use JSON parsing but it does not work. How can I get the json?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [API documentation for the `data` field](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/swift/firebasefunctions/api/reference/Classes/HTTPSCallableResult#data) states:

> The data is in the form of native objects. For example, if your
>   trigger returned an array, this object would be an NSArray. If your
>   trigger returned a JavaScript object with keys and values, this object
>   would be an NSDictionary.

Since you're sending an array of objects from your function, you would treat the contents of `data` as an `NSArray` of `NSDictionary` objects.

Comment: Hey Doug, thanks! Cannot assign value of type 'HTTPSCallableResult' to type '[String : Any]' or if I do this: array = result?.data as! [String: Any] the app crashes

Comment: With this response, it works: var result = {
            "data": array
        };

        response.send(result)

Comment: Did you manage to get this solved?